# how to remove "search" word from <input placeholder="search" >?

Tags: html, css

when I write `<input class="search-bar" placeholder="search" >`, automatically it fills our search bar with the word "search".
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tLyO.png)

first question is I want to get rid of it and second question is when I fill this search bar with typing something, I want to show nothing when I deselect the search bar (click somewhere else).
[I deselected search bar by clicking somewhere else but it still showing my text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Y5d.png)

Comment: What did you think the `placeholder` attribute was for?

Comment: Have you tried... removing the attribute which specifies that placeholder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the attribute placeholder.